# Room void methods on main thread

Tags: android-room

When using the Room library for Android the documentation clearly states that we cannot make calls on the main thread unless we specifically allow them. What I'm curious about is methods that have a `void` return type. It seems silly that returning `LiveData` will automatically run them off the main thread, but void types will not (unless I'm missing something). Is there any easy way I can do this without having to run this in my own managed thread?

My Query:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("DELETE FROM users")
    fun clear()
}
```

I've even tried using Kotlin reflection + extension functions, but this seemed to fail during runtime:

```
fun KFunction<Unit>.execOn(executor: Executor, vararg args: Any?) {
    executor.execute {
        this.call(args)
    }
}
```

Then make a call like:

```
myDb.userDao()::clear.execOn(diskExecutor)
```

Note what does work is:

```
diskExecutor.execute {
    myDb.userDao().clear()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems silly that returning LiveData will automatically run them off the main thread, but void types will not (unless I'm missing something).

Without some sort of annotation, Room would have no idea that you want a `void`-returning DAO method to be run on a background thread. With a reactive return type (e.g., `LiveData`, `Single`), you are explicitly requesting background execution, so no additional metadata (e.g., an annotation) is required.

You might consider filing a feature request for such an annotation-based approach.

> Is there any easy way I can do this without having to run this in my own managed thread?

If you are asking "does Room have a background-execution option for DAO methods other than those with reactive return types?", then the answer is no, at least at the present time.

Comment: Yeah, so other than getting Google to implement a new annotation, which would take a while, I was hoping there would be a way around it like returning LiveData<Void> (doesn't work)

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer: Room 2.1.0 looks like it will ship with `Completable` support for `@Insert`, `@Update`, and `@Delete`. They don't mention `@Query`, so that might require a future feature request. See [the release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes#october_8_2018) and [the relevant issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/63317956).